# connect same ids with values in id rows (result of effectiveELD)

Tags: python

I can't cope with reworking the result. If id is the same I want to stick those items.

```
with open(x,'r') as rf:
    l = fr.readlines()
    previous_line_id = ''
    corrected_lines = []

    for i in l:
       i_split = i.split('\t')
       id_ = i_split[0]
       if id_ == previous_line
           xxxxxxxxxx
       else:
           corrected_lines .append(i)
```

result:

```
    WP_XXXXXXXX2.1  PF06325 Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  5
    WP_192XXXXXX.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
    XXXXXXX45.1 PF02310 B12 binding domain  12  <-----------  DOUBLE IDS
    XXXXXXX45.1 PF04055 Radical SAM superfamily 5 <-----------
    WP_XXXXXXX29.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
    WP_0XXXXXXXX.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
    WP_XXXXXXX90.1  PF06325 Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  5  <--------------   DOUBLE ID
    WP_XXXXXXX90.1  PF06325 Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  7  <--------------
    WP_0XXXXXX62.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
```

result I need:

```
WP_XXXXXXXX2.1  PF06325 Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  5
WP_192XXXXXX.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
XXXXXXX45.1 PF02310 B12 binding domain  12; PF04055 Radical SAM superfamily 5 <----------- STICKED SAME ID,OTHER VALUES
WP_XXXXXXX29.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
WP_0XXXXXXXX.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
WP_XXXXXXX90.1  PF06325 Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  5; PF06325  Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  7  <--------- STICKED STICKED SAME ID,OTHER VALUES
WP_0XXXXXX62.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand what you want exactly. Could you please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @user324810 I commented text

Comment: @user324810 I want to remove the double id and merge their values together

Comment: Thank you. Give me a moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the file `test.txt` is tab-separated values with these fields:

```
WP_XXXXXXXX2.1  PF06325     Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)      5
WP_192XXXXXX.1  PF13489     Methyltransferase domain                            4
XXXXXXX45.1     PF02310     B12 binding domain                                  12 
XXXXXXX45.1     PF04055     Radical SAM superfamily                             5
WP_XXXXXXX29.1  PF13489     Methyltransferase domain                            4
WP_0XXXXXXXX.1  PF13489     Methyltransferase domain                            4
WP_XXXXXXX90.1  PF06325     Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)      5
WP_XXXXXXX90.1  PF06325     Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)      7
WP_0XXXXXX62.1  PF13489     Methyltransferase domain                            4
```

You can proceed first by reading your file:

```
with open("test.txt",'r') as rf:
    l = rf.readlines() # all the lines are stored in variable 'l'
```

You should create a dictionary with your ID as keys and the remaining line as values:

```
# create empty dictionary
dict_id = {}

for i in l:                                                               # for each line
    key_id = i.split("\t")[0]                                             # get the id
    if key_id not in dict_id.keys():                                      # if id as key is not found in dictionary
        value = "\t".join(i.split("\t")[1:]).rstrip()                     # parse the value
        dict_id[key_id] = [value]                                         # add the id as key to dictionary with its value
    else:                                                                 # else if id as key is already in dictionary
        dict_id[key_id].append("\t".join(i.split("\t")[1:]).rstrip())     # append to id as key
```

And now, you can print the result:

```
for key, value in dict_id.items():         # for each key, values in dictionary
    print(key + ": " + "; ".join(value))   # print the key and their values separated by '; '
```

And you should obtain:

```
WP_XXXXXXXX2.1: PF06325 Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  5
WP_192XXXXXX.1: PF13489 Methyltransferase domain        4
XXXXXXX45.1: PF02310    B12 binding domain      12; PF04055     Radical SAM superfamily 5
WP_XXXXXXX29.1: PF13489 Methyltransferase domain        4
WP_0XXXXXXXX.1: PF13489 Methyltransferase domain        4
WP_XXXXXXX90.1: PF06325 Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  5; PF06325      Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  7
WP_0XXXXXX62.1: PF13489 Methyltransferase domain        4
```

The final script:

```
with open("test.txt",'r') as rf:
    l = rf.readlines()

dict_id = {}
for i in l:
    key_id = i.split("\t")[0]
    if key_id not in dict_id.keys():
        value = "\t".join(i.split("\t")[1:]).rstrip()
        dict_id[key_id] = [value] 
    else:
        dict_id[key_id].append("\t".join(i.split("\t")[1:]).rstrip())

for key, value in dict_id.items():
    print(key + ": " + "; ".join(value))
```

Comment: realy thanks :) all best