# if, else statment gives back else value

Tags: python

I have a list of protein sequence ids (names). I want to sort the lines of a table, checking if the id is equal to the first column of the table. I split the table on lines and search for the id via regex:

code:

```
def map_line_to_ids(id):
    id= id.strip('\n')
    for s in lines:
        if re.search(id,s):
            return s #<------------ why always return else not if(s) when takes empty 'def'
        else:
            return id + '\n'

names = ['XXXXXXX45.1', 'YP_343434.1', 'WP_XXXXXXXX2.1', 'WP_XXXXXXX90.1',
         'WP_0XXXXXX62.1', 'XP_222222222.2', 'WP_192XXXXXX.1',
         'WP_XXXXXXX29.1', 'WP_0XXXXXXXX.1']

sorted_lines = list(map(map_line_to_ids, names))
```

names (order):

```
XXXXXXX45.1
YP_343434.1
WP_XXXXXXXX2.1
WP_XXXXXXX90.1
WP_0XXXXXX62.1
XP_222222222.2
WP_192XXXXXX.1
WP_XXXXXXX29.1
WP_0XXXXXXXX.1
```

Input table:

```
WP_XXXXXXXX2.1  PF06325 Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  5
WP_192XXXXXX.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
XXXXXXX45.1 PF02310 B12 binding domain  12; PF04055 Radical SAM superfamily 5 
WP_XXXXXXX29.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
WP_0XXXXXXXX.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
WP_XXXXXXX90.1  PF06325 Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  5; PF06325  Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  7  
WP_0XXXXXX62.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
```

Expected output:

```
XXXXXXX45.1 PF02310 B12 binding domain  12; PF04055 Radical SAM superfamily 5
YP_343434.1
WP_XXXXXXXX2.1  PF06325 Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  5
WP_XXXXXXX90.1  PF06325 Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  5; PF06325  Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  7
XP_222222222.2  
WP_0XXXXXX62.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
WP_192XXXXXX.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
WP_XXXXXXX29.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
WP_0XXXXXXXX.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
```

Comment: Hi @MTG, this is a pure programming question, so it would have been appropriate to ask on StackOverflow. But I think we're happy to handle it here on Bioinformatics as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on your [last post](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/18412/connect-same-ids-with-values-in-id-rows-result-of-effectiveeld/18413#18413), your initial file `test.txt` looks like that:

```
WP_XXXXXXXX2.1  PF06325 Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  5
WP_192XXXXXX.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
XXXXXXX45.1 PF02310 B12 binding domain  12
XXXXXXX45.1 PF04055 Radical SAM superfamily 5
WP_XXXXXXX29.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
WP_0XXXXXXXX.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
WP_XXXXXXX90.1  PF06325 Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  5
WP_XXXXXXX90.1  PF06325 Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  7
WP_0XXXXXX62.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain    4
```

And you have another file `order.txt` that contains your ordered IDs:

```
XXXXXXX45.1
YP_343434.1
WP_XXXXXXXX2.1
WP_XXXXXXX90.1
WP_0XXXXXX62.1
XP_222222222.2
WP_192XXXXXX.1
WP_XXXXXXX29.1
WP_0XXXXXXXX.1
```

Since you want to merge by the first field in `test.txt` and sort them according to `order.txt`, you have to read first both of the files:

```
# read 'test.txt'
with open("test.txt",'r') as rf:
    l = rf.readlines()

# read sorted IDs 'order.txt'
with open("order.txt",'r') as rf:
    l_order = rf.readlines()

# remove newlines from each element in list
l_order = [i.strip() for i in l_order]
```

My previous answers describe how we obtain the merged fields in the file, so I will not go over it again. Since we need to sort the dictionary according to the list, we simply have to do:

```
# for each element in ordered list
for i in l_order:
    if i in dict_id.keys():                        # if element is in my dictionary's keys
        print(i + "\t" + "; ".join(dict_id[i]))    # print the key and the value
    else:
        print(i)                                   # else prints the element
```

This should print:

```
XXXXXXX45.1     PF02310 B12 binding domain      12; PF04055     Radical SAM superfamily 5
YP_343434.1
WP_XXXXXXXX2.1  PF06325 Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  5
WP_XXXXXXX90.1  PF06325 Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  5; PF06325      Ribosomal protein L11 methyltransferase (PrmA)  7
WP_0XXXXXX62.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain        4
XP_222222222.2
WP_192XXXXXX.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain        4
WP_XXXXXXX29.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain        4
WP_0XXXXXXXX.1  PF13489 Methyltransferase domain        4
```

Full code:

```
with open("test.txt",'r') as rf:
    l = rf.readlines()

with open("order.txt",'r') as rf:
    l_order = rf.readlines()

l_order = [i.strip() for i in l_order]

dict_id = {}
for i in l:
    key_id = i.split("\t")[0]
    if key_id not in dict_id.keys():
        value = "\t".join(i.split("\t")[1:]).rstrip()
        dict_id[key_id] = [value] 
    else:
        dict_id[key_id].append("\t".join(i.split("\t")[1:]).rstrip())

for i in l_order:
    if i in dict_id.keys():
        print(i + "\t" + "; ".join(dict_id[i]))
    else:
        print(i)
```

PS: please for further pure programming questions, do post your questions in StackOverflow instead of Bioinformatics.